# Persistent Warning: "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique 'key' prop" even if key is already set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to figure about the warning that react had been showing. Clearly I have the tags set with key yet the warning still insists.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {Object.entries(this.props.rowData).map(rowData => 
                        <tr key={rowData.id}> 
                            {Object.entries(rowData).map((data, index) =>
                                <td key={index}> Test </td>
                            )}
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: what's the exact shape of `rowData`?

Comment: What is the structure of `this.props.rowData` ?

Comment: @nem035 it looks like this https://pastebin.com/jiASQFkA (there's no nesting)

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are misunderstanding what [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) does.

`Object.entries` returns an array of tuples (array of 2 elements) for each key/value pair it contains:

```js
// logs [["id", 5], ["name", "example"]]
console.log(
  Object.entries(
    { id: 5, name: 'example' }
  )
)
```

What you probably want is [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which will return an array of values from an object.

```js
// logs [5, 'example']
console.log(
  Object.values(
    { id: 5, name: 'example' }
  )
)
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the [data](https://pastebin.com/jiASQFkA) you provided, `rowData` is an array so there's no need to use any `Object.*` methods on it. We can just map on it directly:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="table">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.rowData.map(row => 
                        <tr key={row.id}> 
                            {Object.entries(row).map(([key,value], index) =>
                                <td key={index}> {key},{value} </td>
                            )}
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I also tried Object.values, but still getting the same warning. It points to the <tr> tag somehow.